# URL doesn't go back to original with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, redirect

This is one of the functions of my controller where it will load the page

```
public function view_7th(){
        $floor = "7";
        $data = $this->get_cells($floor);
        $this->load->view('pages/7thFloor', $data);
    }
```

and to activate a cell, here is my code

```
public function activate_cell(){
    $cell = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
    $emp = $this->uri->segment(4, 0);
    $floor = $this->uri->segment(5, 0);

    $this->m_floor->activate_cell($cell, $emp, $floor);

    $this->view_7th();
}
```

it redirects properly but the URL stays

```
http://localhost/seatplan/c_floor/activate_cell/6K/047/7
```

so if the user accidentally refreshes the page, it will be inserted again in the database.
Is I know that you could use **redirect** but is there another option?

Thank you!

Comment: Redirect ***is*** the proper option unless you want to modify the URL using Javascript which has sketchy support at best.

Answer (score 0):

the URI shouldn't change, as a new request wasn't sent. 
This is also true when you send a form BTW, on the success page, if you refresh, you'll submit the form again.(as you refresh the POST reuqest).

you must redirect in order to avoid those issues or add a flag to check if said records are already in the db(if they should be unique).

a user can also bookmark that link for whatever reason and try to get to your page with that link, forcing another entry on the database. 
you'll need to deal with multiple database entries anyway(to make it more secure aswell).